# Move the condition out of JOIN as query slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query that matches records based on CategoryId in Booking and SMSConfiguration.

Here I need to find the records for NULL CategoryId in SMSConfiguration also. I get my expected output. But the query runs 2 mins.

If I remove the additional condition `OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL` in JOIN it runs faster and less than 1 second. I am not sure how to move this out of JOIN.

```
SELECT SMS.Id AS ConfigId
    ,B.BookingId AS BookingId
    ,B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime
    ,B.EndTime AS BookingEndTime
    ,B.BookingDate AS BookingDate
    ,B.Price AS Price

FROM Booking B
INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
    OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL -- CAUSING SLOW
    AND SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId
```

**EDIT:**

***Full Query***

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime SMALLDATETIME

SET @CurrentDateTime='2016-08-11 08:00:00.247'

SELECT SMS.Id AS ConfigId
        ,B.BookingId AS BookingId
        ,B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime
        ,B.EndTime AS BookingEndTime
        ,B.BookingDate AS BookingDate
        ,B.Price AS Price
        ,C.CategoryName AS CategoryName
        ,PER.PersonId AS PersonId
        ,P.PatientId AS PatientId
        ,PER.FirstName AS PatientFirstName
        ,PER.LastName AS PatientLastName
        ,PER.MobileNumber AS PatientMobileNumber
        ,RP.FirstName AS DoctorFirstName
        ,RP.LastName AS DoctorLastName
        ,SMS.SMSText
        ,B.TenantId AS TenantId
    FROM Booking B
    INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
        OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
        AND SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId
    INNER JOIN Tenant T ON T.TenantId = B.TenantId --AND T.IsSMSEnabled=1         
    INNER JOIN Patient P ON B.PatientId = P.PatientId
    INNER JOIN Person PER ON P.PersonId = PER.PersonId
    INNER JOIN Person RP ON RP.PersonId = B.ResponsiblePersonId
    LEFT JOIN Category C ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
    WHERE 
            PER.MobileNumber IS NOT NULL
            AND PER.MobileNumber <> ''

        AND (
                (
                   (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDateTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 1
                    )
                OR (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDateTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration * 7
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 2
                    )
                OR (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDateTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration * 30
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 3
                    )
                )
               AND BeforeAfter = 0

        OR (
            (
                (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, B.StartTime, @CurrentDateTime) = SMS.Duration
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 1
                    )
                OR (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDateTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration * 7
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 2
                    )
                OR (
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDateTime, B.StartTime) = SMS.Duration * 30
                    AND SMS.DurationType = 3
                    )
                )
            AND BeforeAfter = 1
            )
            )
```

**Slow Plan**

[image]

**Fast Plan** when I commented that OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL

[image]

Comment: How many records are returned when it takes 2 minutes? How many for the fast version? What do the query plans say?

Comment: Returns 213 records only. faster returns only 37.

Comment: Please include both query plans.

Comment: should your OR not scan the whole table?

Comment: Turn on the "Include Actual Execution Plan" query option in SSMS and look at the generated plans for both queries.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I have added the execution plan. Thanks for suggestion , i never know about this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Put SMS.CategoryId and B.CategoryId in WHERE condition and then check for null - its more readable that way. Try running the following query, it reduces the table iteration cycle by 1

```
SELECT
    SMS.Id AS ConfigId
    ,B.BookingId AS BookingId
    ,B.StartTime AS BookingStartTime
    ,B.EndTime AS BookingEndTime
    ,B.BookingDate AS BookingDate
    ,B.Price AS Price

FROM
    Booking B
    INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS
        ON SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId
WHERE
    B.CategoryId = ISNULL(SMS.CategoryId,B.CategoryId)
```

Answer (score 1):

OR is almost always slow. Usually it is far faster to use a UNION all query instead. However it is not clear to me exactly what the conditions on the join are supposed to be. Do you mean:

```
 INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON (SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
        OR SMS.CategoryId IS NULL)
        AND SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId
```

Or

```
 INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS ON SMS.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
        OR (SMS.CategoryId IS NULL
        AND SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId)
```

the first is what you are getting, however even if you mean that , you should use () to make it clear when someone goes to maintain this.

Comment: The other answer works somewhat ok for me around 8 secs. `INNER JOIN SMSConfiguration SMS
        ON SMS.TenantId = B.TenantId
WHERE
    B.CategoryId = ISNULL(SMS.CategoryId,B.CategoryId)` The same only I tried but in the JOIN